# MongoDB: Filter on _id == obj._id without setting obj._id to null on insert

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to configure an upsert. If `_id` already exists on my object, it recognizes that and updates the match. If `_id` doesn't exist, it should insert the new document and generate an _id. I'd expect `{ _id: obj._id }` to work, but that overrides the auto-generation of `_id`. The document appears with `_id: null`. Is there a filter that would work for this? Do I need to route to insert/update in-code?

Edit: add query.

```
collection.updateOne(
  { _id: entity._id },
  { $set: entity },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

Edit: try delete.
Even when I delete the property, no luck.

```
const upsertTest = (collection) => {
  const entity = { date: new Date() };
  console.log(entity);
  // { date: 2019-11-19T22:16:00.914Z }

  const _id = entity._id;
  delete entity._id;
  console.log(entity);
  // { date: 2019-11-19T22:16:00.914Z }

  collection.updateOne(
    { _id: _id },
    { $set: entity },
    { upsert: true }
  );

  console.log(entity);
  // { date: 2019-11-19T22:16:00.914Z }
}
```

But the new document is this:
[screenshot of new document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBLfg.png)

Comment: What does your `insertMap()` function do?

Comment: I meant to remove that. In this case it just returns the argument.

Comment: Hang on, I've just Googled around and may have found your answer. Are you making this query to the `local` database? Apparently only the `local` database allows this behavior. Any other DB and it will work.

Comment: Huh. Yes, it's local.

Comment: Yup, you shouldn't use that DB for applications. You should make a new one for each application. I will post this as an answer for you to accept if that fixes it.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I'm hitting a database on my local machine, not the `local` database.

Comment: Ah, alrighty. Then I got nothin. I've been using MongoDB for years and I've never seen it allow an `_id` to be `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [$setOnInsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) to Insert `_id`

```
let ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

collection.updateOne(
 { _id: entity._id },
 { $set: entity,$setOnInsert:{_id:new ObjectID()}},
 { upsert: true }
)
```

As the name suggests it will set the `_id` on `insert`

If you are using `mongodb` then `new ObjectID()` should work,

If its `mongoose` then you can use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` to generate new `ObjectID`

Well I Found your Issue

> Changed in version 3.0: When you execute an update() with upsert: true and the query matches no existing document, MongoDB will refuse to insert a new document if the query specifies conditions on the _id field.

So in a nutshell you cannot insert a new doc using `upsert:true` if your query is using `_id`, [Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-query)

Comment: It makes sense to me that it should work, but I get `MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'`

Comment: Did you delete the `_id` in the `entity` you are passing to `$set`?

Comment: I've tried both ways. I get the error even with an empty collection.

Comment: Oh no! Thanks for the answer, looks like I'll have to find another way.

Comment: It's easy, instead of marking `Upsert:true` check the return value of `UpdateOne`, if none is found you can run `Insert` with same entity

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `_id` property WILL always exist, whether you set it yourself or let it auto-generate. So there's no need to check if it exists.

The syntax for upsert is as follows:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 'the id you want to check for' // can put any valid 'find' query here
}, {
  $set: {
    foo: 'bar',
    biz: 'baz'
  }
}, {
  upsert: true
});
```

If a document with the given `_id` exists, it will be updated with the `$set` object. If it does not exist, a new one will be created with the properties of the `$set` object. If `_id` is not specified in the `$set` object, a new `_id` value will be auto-generated, or will keep using the existing `_id` value.

The key here is using `$set`, rather than putting the object right in there. Using set will merge and replace the properties. Without `$set` it will replace the entire document, removing any unset properties.

Edit: Now seeing the actual query you made, I would suggest you delete the `_id` property from the entity before setting it. This will make sure it is left alone.

```
const _id = entity._id;
delete entity._id;
// now do your query using the new `_id` value for the ID.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! That's the syntax I'm using, though. If I filter on `{ _id: obj._id }`, it inserts `obj` with `_id: null`, even though `_id` isn't present on `obj`. If I filter on another property, `_id` is generated as expected.

Comment: @thorell9 Please edit your original post with the exact query you're making. I know you're new here, but you should always post your code examples when asking questions.

Comment: @thorell9 Updated my answer

Comment: @thorell9 Definitely odd then. In-fact, after a document is created its `_id` can never change, and MongoDB will return an error if you try. So there must be some other code running after your query that removes the `_id`. There's no other possible way.

Answer (score 0):

From our comments you mentioned you were using the `local` database. The `local` database allows `_id` to be null. Using any other DB should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the `entity._id` is `null` then it will create a doc with _id `null`, We can solve this issue by adding `Types.ObjectId()`. If the `_id` doesn't exist then it will create a new document with the proper `_id`. otherwise, it will update the existing document.

```
const { Types } = require("mongoose")

collection.updateOne({ _id: Types.ObjectId(entity._id) },{ $set: entity },{ upsert: true})
```